# Authenticating user without creating app manifest in teams app

Tags: authentication, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, bot-framework-composer

Just because of authentication I need to create an app manifest and share the app manifest with users who want to test it .Is there a way to Authenticate user without creating app manifest so that I can directly share bot link with users.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you have some testers for your Teams bot and you want to allow them to use the bot on Teams without installing it. Is that correct? Why don't you want to create an app manifest?

Comment: Because i need to create it only because of authentication.For everything else the link works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Talking to your bot by ID is intended for basic testing purposes only. Any Teams-specific functionality you have added to your bot fails to work.

Doc ref: [Talk to your bot directly by ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/debug/locally-with-an-ide#talk-to-your-bot-directly-by-id)

Answer (score 0):

[In this example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/java_springboot/18.bot-authentication)
Is is an OAUTH flow with Azure AD directory v2 without any app manifest.
This one is in java_springboot but you can find the same for your prefered langage in the samples directory. The number 18 (and all the others) in all samples is the example but in different langages.